# Flask url_for() doesn't take a second argument even though it's required

Tags: python, flask

I have the following routes

```
@app.route("/dashboard/survey/<int:survey_id>/responses",  methods=["GET"])
def responses(survey_id):
    responses = db.session.query(Survey, Responses).join(Responses).filter(Survey.id == survey_id).filter(
        Responses.lan_code == "en").all()

    return render_template('responses.html', responses=responses, kws=kws)


@app.route("/dashboard/survey/<int:survey_id>/responses/delete/<int:r_id>/<participant_folder>", methods=["POST"])
def delete_response(survey_id, r_id, participant_folder):
    #response = Responses.query.get_or_404(r_id)
    #db.session.delete(response)
    #db.session.commit()
    #pfolder = participant_folder.replace("-", "/")
    #print(pfolder)
    #shutil.rmtree('qdas/static/audioResponses/' + pfolder, ignore_errors=True)
    return redirect(url_for('responses', survey_id))
```

When I try to redirect to 'responses' I get the following error:

> TypeError: url_for() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

And if remove survey_id from the arguments I get this error:

> werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'responses'. Did you forget to specify values ['survey_id']?

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to change this line,

```
return redirect(url_for('responses', survey_id))
```

to this one.

```
return redirect(url_for('responses', survey_id=survey_id))
```

This is because `url_for` accepts only one endpoint with an optional number of arguments.